# save an object in php session (kohana)

Tags: php, object, save, kohana, session-storage

I would like to know why the session management is so diferent in windows wamp and server and then in a linux webhosting server. The thing is that i have coded my aplicattion setting objects in the session, simply like this : 
....
$this->session->set('obj',$obj); 
...

and then recovering this object like :
 $obj = $this->session->get('obj') and after this i could call operations of course
 $obj->someMethod();

When I put online this code I found out that this doesnt work, I was reading lot of posts, suggesting about serializing the object, but I see that most of developers just save in the session the id of the object. Someone knows why one enviroment ( wamp server of windows) allows this and the other enviroment ( linux server) doesnt allow this?

Is there any criteria? Couldn't be things a litle more standard or compatible so we developer avoid losing time on this?

Thanks.

Comment: I work exclusively in a Linux environment and I regularly store objects in sessions without trouble. I feel that the first thing you need to do is check the version of PHP on the server to ensure it isn't archaic.

Comment: What is the PHP version your are using on WAMP ? and the PHP version you are using on Linux Server ?

Comment: the php version in the webhosting server is 5.4. On my localhost (windows/wamp) is 5.3.13

Comment: PHP Sessions automatically serialize/deserialize objects. If the exact same code works on Windows but fails on Linux, the problem is most likely your PHP configuration or a permission issue.

Comment: can be possible that the wehhosting server doesnt have this permission? strange..do you know whick kind of configuration is needed?